# using JQuery autocomplete from database with PHP (CodeIgniter)

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, codeigniter

So I want to use this plugin http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/autocomplete

I want to retrieve all the user names from database using codeigniter then store them in a var in javascript (If this is a good way) then use it in autocomplete. Also, I want the user if he/she enters any other text it wont be accepted, it has to be already stored in database only.

Thanx in advanced :)

Comment: Are you wanting us to write the code for you? Are you having trouble with something in particular? How about you give it a shot, and we'll help you along the way?

Comment: I tried to do it, but I dont understand how to use a database with it. If its a simple var then OK, but getting from database is a bit difficult for me, I didn't entirely understand how to do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, Here is how I would structure it:

First, you have to create a file to serve your data from your backend database. According to the [jQuery Autocomplete Docs](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Autocomplete/autocomplete#url_or_dataoptions), your backend will need to return a list of options **one per line**.

Let's call our php file, get_results.php:

```
<?php

// Do your DB calls here to fill an array of results
$arrResults = array('option 1', 'option 2', 'option 3');

// Print them out, one per line
echo implode("\n", $arrResults);
```

Then, in your JavaScript code, you'd do something like this:

```
$("#myTextBox").autocomplete('get_results.php');
```

That is the very basic of how I would do it. Hopefully, you  can go from there. Here are some important resources:

- [PHP Basics](http://php.net/manual/en/tutorial.php)
- [PHP Database Connections](http://www.php-mysql-tutorial.com/wikis/mysql-tutorials/connect-to-mysql-database.aspx)
- [jQuery Autocomplete Docs](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Autocomplete/autocomplete)

Comment: No problem. One more thing: In codeigniter, you'll just use the MVC approach to get your data and display it. Create a controller, add a method called, say get_results, grab the data from your model, and use the controller to print it out using the method above. Easy peasy. Good luck!