# JQuery ui autocomplete with php (codeigniter) and database

Tags: php, jquery-ui

I have this ac.php file and this result.php file
I want to use the autocomplete in JQuery UI in the ac.php file, but I want it to retrieve the data from result.php as a source. I just dont know how to do it. I tried this way, but its not working

**ac.php**

```
<html>
<head>
    <link type="text/css" href="jqui/css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.8.11.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" />  
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jqui/js/jquery-1.5.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jqui/js/jquery-ui-1.8.11.custom.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#tags").autocomplete("result.php");
    });

  </script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="ui-widget">
    <label for="tags">Tags: </label>
    <input id="tags">
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

this is **result.php**

```
<?php
$arrResults = array('option 1', 'option 2', 'option 3');

// Print them out, one per line
echo implode("\n", $arrResults); 

?>
```

Comment: try returning it as a jsonstring `json_encode($arrResults)`. Also, have you checked on firbug to see whether the request/response is ok?

Comment: This is just the code you were given from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5487872/using-jquery-autocomplete-from-database-with-php-codeigniter) - are you asking how to integrate this with codeigniter specifically?

Comment: @Ross no, I can do it with codeigniter. The problem is when I used JQuery UI. its not retrieving the sample information

Comment: Hello, the error console of FireFox printed an error message. According of the documentation the method '.autocomplete()' needs the data in form of JSON.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quoting the [documentation of Autocomplete](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Autocomplete) :

> the Autocomplete plugin expects that
> string to point to a URL resource that
> will return **JSON data**.

So, instead of your code, you should use something like this :

```
<?php
$arrResults = array('option 1', 'option 2', 'option 3');
echo json_encode($arrResults);
?>
```

The [**`json_encode()`**][2] function will return the JSON string that corresponds to your array.

Comment: I hope your still around :p .. I did exactly what you said and it worked. But I noticed something. Whatever i write the bar displays all words in the array. It doesnt comply what what the user enters.

Answer (score 1):

**ac.php**

```
$(function() {
    $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
        source: "result.php",
        dataType:'json',
        minLength: 0,
        delay:0

    });

    $( "#tags" ).click(function() {
        $( "#tags" ).autocomplete("search","");
    });
});
```

**result.php**

```
<?php
$arrResults = array('option 1', 'option 2', 'option 3');

// Print them out, one per line
echo json_encode($arrResults);
?>
```

Comment: I tried your way, but it didnt work :( + I dont understand the the second function, why use it?

Comment: The second function allows you to "autocomplete" on click and not only when you type something in the input.